# How to include a platform-specific example, or only compile the example conditionally

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to conditionally include an `[[example]]`? I have an example which only runs on *nix, so it causes errors on windows.

I'm trying to avoid writing `#[cfg(not(target_family = "windows"))]` on every single top-level item in `main.rs`, and I also don't want to compromise the code structure (introducing extra modules) or mess up IDE integration ideally.

---

Changing `[[example]]` to `[[target.'cfg(not(target_family = "windows"))'.example]]` (in `Cargo.toml`) did not work.

---

Adding `#![cfg(not(target_family = "windows"))]` to the top of the file causes:

> `main` function not found in crate `my_example`

Adding `#![cfg_attr(target_family = "windows", crate_type = "lib")]` does not get around this as:

> `crate_type` within an `#![cfg_attr] attribute is deprecated`

---

Also tried using a declarative macro, but it doesn't actually work (seems `item` doesn't match `mod`ules), and isn't ideal even if it did work as it messes with IDE assistance.

```rust
macro_rules! no_windows {
    (
        $( x:item )*
    ) => {
        $(
            #[cfg(not(target_family = "windows"))]
            $x
        )*

        #[cfg(target_family = "windows")]
        fn main() {
            unimplemented!();
        }
    };
}

no_windows! {

// normal code here

}
```

Comment: Put `#![cfg(not(target_family = "windows"))]` at the top of `example.rs`

Comment: @PitaJ results in "`main` function not found in crate `my_example`", did try this Ill add it to the question

Answer (score 3):

There might be a better way, but something like this should work

```rust
#[cfg(not(target_family = "windows"))]
mod non_windows {
    // ...
    
    pub fn main() {
        // ...
    }
}

fn main() {
    #[cfg(not(target_family = "windows"))]
    non_windows::main();
}
```